# How to enable HTTPS in a Spring Boot application, deployed as WAR file in Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring-boot, https, war

I have a Spring Boot application, deployed as WAR file in a Tomcat in AWS.

However, I do need to enable HTTPS on it. There are other applications in same server which are already using HTTPS with no problems.

DNS and SSL certificates are managed by GoDaddy. I have already downloaded the certificate, a wildcard one, that is also used for other applications in server.

How can I enable HTTPS for a Spring Boot WAR deployed application?

*I've tried this tutorial, following 1b, as I already have GoDaddy's certificate.
https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/*

**EDIT:** Tomcat is already configured for SSL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Tomcat to enable SSL. You can take a look in here: https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-ssl

Comment: It is already configured. Other applications (non-spring-boot) already use it. HTTPS works with no problems.